# push multiple views from TableView to Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

my app looks like this

`UINavigationController` with `UITableViewcontroller` as RootViewController.

```
feedsTableViewController = [[ablogFeedsTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
feedsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:feedsTableViewController];
feedsNavigationController.delegate = feedsTableViewController;
```

in my viewcontroller method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` im calling another tableview controller like this:

```
ablogSingleCatTableViewController *singleCatTableViewController = [[ablogSingleCatTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain category:[categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:singleCatTableViewController animated:YES];
[singleCatTableViewController release];
```

this works fine.

now in this pushed UITableView i try to push a UIView, but this does not work.

```
postView = [[ablogPostView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:postView animated:YES];
[postView release];
```

i think the problem is at [self navigationController] because the delegate of this navigationController is in my other UITableViewController.

anybode can help me, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't push several viewControllers with an animation. Only the last push should be animated.

Also: it appears that you are trying to push a UIView subclass onto the navigationController. This won't work and you should have seen a warning. You can only push ViewControllers onto the stack.

Comment: ah okay. i really created a uiView instead of a UIViewController.
I still have problems with the difference of ViewController and View. Why shoudn't i animate only the last one?

Comment: That should be a new question. But a view is an object that describes presentation, but has no idea of how to be pushed around on a navigation controller.

Comment: If you push two viewControllers with an animation the navigationController messes up the animation and titles and you will get weird effects when trying to pop back.